# # of hosts that can be on the same network as my computer VS # of hosts that can be on the same subnet as my computer

Tags: java, networking, ipv4

What is the difference between the number of hosts that can be on the same network as my computer and the number of hosts that can be on the same subnet as my computer?

Comment: How do you define "same network as my computer"?

Comment: My professor phrased it exactly like this: "can someone tell me how many hosts can be on the same network as your computer?" "can someone tell me how many hosts can be on the same subnet as your computer?" I assume he's acquiring these numbers from the IPV4 address and subnet mask, but I'm not sure where to go from there.